# Creating a unique integer on the basis of a string

Tags: r, data.table

I have a larger dataset (data.table with approx 9m rows) with a column that I would like to use to aggregate values (min and max etc). The column is a combination of various other columns and has a string based format, like the one below:

```
string <- "318XXXX | VNSGN | BIER"
```

To gain some speed in performing tasks, I would like to recode this to a unique integer. Another application that I use on a regular basis to deal with data has a build-in function that transforms a string as the one above in a integer (e.g. 73823). I was wondering whether there is a similar function in R? The idea is that a particular string will always result in the same integer; this will allow it to be used in merging data.tables etc.

Here a little example of the data.table column that I would like to encode in simple integer values:

```
sample <- c("318XXXX | VNSGN | BIER", "462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905", "462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905", 
"462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905", "511XXXX | FAWOR | 336H", "511XXXX | FAWOR | 336H", 
"652XXXX | XXXXR | T136", "652XXXX | XXXXR | T136", "672XXXX | BQQSZ | 7777", 
"672XXXX | BQQSZ | 7777")
```

I am hoping to encode the strings into an additional column to the table like the one below; note that the same strings result in the same numbers.

```
String                      Number
318XXXX | VNSGN | BIER      19872
462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905      78392
462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905      78392
462XXXX | TZZZH | 9905      78392
511XXXX | FAWOR | 336H      23053
511XXXX | FAWOR | 336H      23053
652XXXX | XXXXR | T136      95832
652XXXX | XXXXR | T136      95832
672XXXX | BQQSZ | 7777      71829   
672XXXX | BQQSZ | 7777      71829
```

Comment: Does `?factor` do what you're looking for?

Comment: @Justin: character strings have been hashed in R for quite some time, so factors won't be more efficient (and may be slower).  But perhaps `as.integer(factor(sample))` is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @Justin To me it looks like `factor` is doing something slightly different then I am trying to do. For example the `?factor` includes the following example `factor(letters[1:20], labels="letter")` which results in `letter1  letter2 (...) letter20`. Am I missing something in the `factor` documentation? I have added a table to question that indicates what I try to accomplish. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I think that `as.integer(factor(sample))` was, in fact, what Justin was referring to.

Comment: @joran you are correct.  I figured I would leave that portion of the exercise to the reader...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data.table package will create indexes for you without making you handle them explicitly so it would be less work than the approach in the question.  See the `setkey` function in data.table.

Also the sqldf package can use the SQL `create index` statement as per Examples 4h and 4i on the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) as can just about any database package.

Comment: Thus, when I use `setkey` in my `data.table` then there is no reason to encode the string in the integer values myself?